# Flickr API returns inconsistent number of photos when using multiple tags

Tags: php, api, flickr

I'm trying to use my Flickr account as a 'host' for an image gallery. I've tagged 251 photos with a common tag 'golftournament' and each one with the year and any players in the photo.

So, for example, three random photos may have the following tags:

`golftournament dan steve 2005` (dan and steve in this photo from 2006)

`golftournament 2006` (no players in this photo from 2006)

`golftournament 2008 paul dan` (paul and dan in this photo from 2008)

When I make an API call, it returns an inconsistent total number of photos if I set the 'tags' part of the API call to `tags=golftournament,dan,2005` and the tag_mode to `tagmode=all`.

Sometimes I get 13 photos in the result, sometimes I get 12 photos and sometimes I actually get the correct number of photos (14)

I'm using a PHP library, but that's irrelevant because I see the same results in the Flickr API Explorer: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/?method=flickr.photos.search)

Is there any reason why the Flickr API is so inconsistent in this regard?

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update on this, in the end I simply got **all** photos from a photoset and then built two arrays of years and players from the tags. Finally, I used what the request was to return the correct photographs. I'm using the excellent [phpFlickr library](http://phpflickr.com) and here's my entire API script:

```
<?php
// Initialise Flickr API library and authentication
require_once("phpFlickr.php");
$f = new phpFlickr('<api key>', '<secret>');
$f->setToken('<token>');

// Get all photos from the photoset
$page = 0;
$perpage = 500;
$all = array('photos' => array(), 'total' => 0);
while ($perpage * $page < $all['total'] || $all['total'] == 0) {
    $p = $f->photosets_getPhotos('<photoset number>', 'tags', NULL, $perpage, $page + 1);
    $all['total'] = (integer) $p['photoset']['total'];
    $all['photos'] += $p['photoset']['photo'];
    $page++;
}

// Get all the available years/players from the tags
$years = array();
$players = array();
foreach ($all['photos'] as $key => $photo) {
    $photo_tags = explode(' ', $photo['tags']);
    $all['photos'][$key]['tags'] = $photo_tags;
    foreach ($photo_tags as $tag) {
        if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}$/', $tag)) {
            if (!in_array($tag, $years)) {
                $years[] = $tag;
            }
        } else {
            if (!in_array($tag, $players)) {
                $players[] = $tag;
            }
        }
    }
}
rsort($years);
sort($players);

// Set year/player tags if set
$tags = array();
if (isset($_GET['year']) && in_array($_GET['year'], $years)) {
    $tags['year'] = $_GET['year'];
}
if (isset($_GET['player']) && in_array($_GET['player'], $players)) {
    $tags['player'] = $_GET['player'];
}

// Build output array and filter by year/person
$output = array(
    'years'     => $years,
    'players'   => $players,
    'photos'    => array()
);
foreach ($all['photos'] as $key => $photo) {
    if (!isset($tags['year']) || in_array($tags['year'], $photo['tags'])) {
        if (!isset($tags['player']) || in_array($tags['player'], $photo['tags'])) {
            $output['photos'][] = array(
                'thumbnail' => $f->buildPhotoURL($photo, 'Square'),
                'image'     => $f->buildPhotoURL($photo, 'Large'),
                'tags'      => implode(' ', $photo['tags'])
            );
        }
    }
}
$output['totals']['total'] = count($output['photos']);

// Calculate paging
$output['perpages'] = array(32, 64, 128, 256);
if (isset($_GET['perpage']) && in_array($_GET['perpage'], $output['perpages'])) {
    $output['perpage'] = $_GET['perpage'];
} else {
    $output['perpage'] = $output['perpages'][0];
}
if ($output['totals']['total'] <= $output['perpage']) {
    $output['pages'] = 1;
} else {
    $output['pages'] = ceil($output['totals']['total'] / $output['perpage']);
}
if (isset($_GET['page']) && intval($_GET['page']) > 0 && intval($_GET['page']) <= $output['pages']) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page = 1;
}
$output['totals']['recordstart'] = (($page == 1) ? 0 : (($page - 1) * $output['perpage']));
$output['totals']['recordend'] = ($output['totals']['recordstart'] + $output['perpage']) - 1;
if ($output['totals']['recordend'] > ($output['totals']['total'] - 1)) {
    $output['totals']['recordend'] = $output['totals']['total'] - 1;
}
$photos = array();
foreach ($output['photos'] as $index => $photo) {
    if ($index >= $output['totals']['recordstart'] && $index <= $output['totals']['recordend']) {
        $photos[] = $photo;
    }
}
unset($output['photos']);
$output['photos'] = $photos;

ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
echo json_encode($output);
```

Hope someone finds this useful!

Dan

Comment: And as I solved my own problem, I'm going to accept my own answer!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the flickr search functionality is [bugged at the moment](http://www.flickr.com/help/forum/en-us/72157625560721827/) and flickr is working on a fix.